# tagging questions from the users' perspective

Tags: discussion, tags

If [questions from the users' perspective](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/should-we-accept-questions-about-moderation-issues-from-users-points-of-view) are acceptable, how should they be tagged?

I was about to ask a question from a user's perspective and there doesn't appear to be a tag for that yet.

I was thinking about creating a [users-point-of-view](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users-point-of-view) or perhaps a [user-perspective](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-perspective), but I thought I should test the water first.

Answer (score 6):

Those sound kind of like meta tags to me.  The *topics* should be largely the same regardless of which "side" they're asked from -- conflict-resolution, new users, community engagement, user behavior, etc.  I've asked [one question explicitly from a user perspective](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/183/83) and didn't feel the need for a user-perspective tag, for what that's worth.  (Maybe not a lot, but early in beta we don't have a lot of data yet.)  Do you have any specific questions in mind?